# HTML to XML conversion with C++

Tags: c++, html, xml

Is there a C++ code or library to convert a HTML document to a XML document?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean html to xhtml? As it is now, there is no meaning to your question, 'xml' is abstract, you can't convert something to it without something more specific in mind.

Comment: Yes, I want to convert to xhtml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at [Tidy library](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/libintro.html)

> Tidy is composed from an HTML parser
>   and an HTML pretty printer. The parser
>   goes to considerable lengths to
>   correct common markup errors. It also
>   provides advice on how to make your
>   pages more accessible to people with
>   disabilities, and can be used to
>   convert HTML content into XML as
>   XHTML.

The library is written in C.

Comment: Do you know any example to use it?

Comment: There is a simple example on the link I gave you. (http://tidy.sourceforge.net/libintro.html#example)

Answer (score 1):

If your XHTML is properly formed, then it is pretty much XML.

If you use [any C++ xml parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c) you can load the document.. and hope it can parse it, then write it back out again.

Comment: `<ul><li>one<li>two<li>three</ul>` is valid HTML 4 strict, but is not xml.

Comment: I have already tried, but it didn't work. I'm using libxml++ 2.6

Comment: @Jeff, I know.  I added an (X) in front.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to convert to XML to parse it with libxml++, but I found this library:
http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/
With it I can parse XML and HTML without any conversion.