# Is there a C++ cross platform key/value API or library for C++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, persistence, key-value-store

We want to persist some user settings int he GUI part of our code.  I used to do Win32 programming exclusively and the typical way this was done was with registry settings.

I assume that this should be done with configuration files, but was wondering if there was a library or cross platform wrapper that made key/value pair persistence very easy.

Answer (score 7):

Qt's QSettings class handles this:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsettings.html

Answer (score 7):

[Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html) supports XML, JSON, INI config files.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [JSON](http://www.json.org/) for a lighter alternative of XML.  Lots of implementations on that page too.

Answer (score 2):

[Qt 4](http://qt.nokia.com/) has a class for it, named [QSettings](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qsettings.html). Looks exactly like what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an XML as the configuration file. Then you only have to find a cross platform XML library which is easier IMO.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c) is a list of nice XML parsing solutions for C++.

Comment: I am not a fan of XML - it is far too heavyweight and I find it pretty unreadable.  I try not to propagate this standard if I can help it.

Answer (score 1):

Old school [Berkley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) comes to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Tokyo Cabinet](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/) or at [Embedded InnoDB](http://www.innodb.com/wp/products/embedded-innodb/).

Answer (score 1):

In the old days we used .ini files in windows. [Here is a portable version of an ini file read/write library](http://code.jellycan.com/simpleini/)
It will work on Windows as well as Linux.