# Managing XML in C++

Tags: c++, xml

I need to manage (parse and build) XML in my c++ application but I have no idea about libraries that can help me doing that. I searched in Boost but found none, std namespace sure does not provide such functionalities. Is there a free c++ library to manage xml?

Thank you

Comment: libxml -> http://xmlsoft.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best open XML parser for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c)

Comment: Well.... yeah it is a duplicate.... goddamn I searched before questioning but found no similar questions.... I'am very sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [TinyXML](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/)
- [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)
- [RapidXml](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/)
- [others](http://www.google.com/search?q=xml+c%2B%2B)

Comment: Thankyou, which one do you think is the best?

Comment: It totally depends on your needs. TinyXML is tiny but a bit slow and resource hungry and lacking features, Xerces is feature complete but huge, RapidXml is fast but lacking features.

Answer (score 0):

[Arabica](http://www.jezuk.co.uk/cgi-bin/view/arabica) is a very nice and standard-friendly wrapper for different XML parsers.