# c++ xml, tcp/ip libraries for Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, xml, windows, linux, tcp

I have this C# client that's handling xml and tcp/ip messages, and I have to convert it to C++, BUT - I have to convert it to C++ in such a way that it will run on both Windows and Linux. Is there a set of standard libraries for xml and tcp/ip that I can use on both Windows and Linux? Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question - I'm very familiar with C# and .NET, but I'm not very familiar with native C++ - I don't really know any of the standard libraries, just the syntax.

In case it helps, here's the exact message from the boss.

> 1) read/create very simple XML, and
>
> 2) receive/send TCP messages from C++ using a library that exists on both Windows and Linux. Hopefully there is one and you can then develop on Windows and just do a quick test on Linux.

Comment: Check [Boost](http://www.boost.org/).

Comment: XML parser/library: maybe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c. Cross-platform networking library -> [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) is a possibility.

Comment: C# can run on linux too - http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page

Comment: At http://lars.ruoff.free.fr/xmlcpp/ there's a comparison of free XML libraries. Maybe it's helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/) will do what you want.

- [TCP Sockets](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qtcpsocket.html)
- [XML Parsing](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtxml.html)

Also seconding Dani's suggestion that you might as well try to run C# applications on [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) before porting to C++.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I ended up using Boost Asio.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt framework not only provides graphical toolkits, but also a C++ framework for portable network applications (same code using Qt should work on Windows, Linux, MacOSX), notably thru its [QtNetwork](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtnetwork.html) module. (You can use Qt without any graphics involved).

Answer (score 0):

Themel has already answer this. I just want to help with this answer.
When i was implementing this in QT4 it gives error: QtNetwork and QTWidget not found. To solve this error in QT4 - 
1. remove #include  and add #include 
2. add QT += network in your project (.pro) file.