# Generating OCX / DLL files to call REST APIs using native C++

Tags: rest, visual-c++, navision

I have a primitive version of Microsoft Navision from which I need to call a 3rd party REST API for get / put / post requests. Is there a way to do that using native C++ code?

Comment: Refer to question http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/52709/274085.aspx#274085 for a detailed description on what is exactly desired.

Comment: LS Retail 2.0 uses Navision Financials 2.60

Answer (score 0):

You could write an IP frame and send it over a TCP socket to port 80. Of course there are probably libraries that can do that for you.

[See previous StackOverflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069741/c-xml-tcp-ip-libraries-for-windows-and-linux)

[Example Library](http://www.komodia.com/tcpip-library-v5-1/)

Comment: Thanks Dennis. Can you just change the url of previous stackoverflow questions? they point to the same link.

Comment: @SushantKhurana oops... fixed.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you a little late. This does solve my problem related to a C++ library. But doesn't answer my question completely. I am not sure how Navision / LS Retail / Microsoft dynamics incorporate 3rd party dlls (which call our REST APIs)

Comment: Navision is as MS product right? And you want to get it to call your REST service? Well I don't know that product... you would probably be better off contacting their customer service.

Comment: I did. Posted on their forum as well. No answer. I'm surprised they don't even see their official forums when they charge a lot for the enterprise product. weird.

Comment: Also, I saw chilkat. It was pretty well defined in terms of HTTP REST CALLS. But it's quite expensive. Could you suggest a better library other than the one you've mentioned. I explored POCO and Boost but they're too heavy.

Comment: I haven't used any but Boost myself so cannot recommend anything else.