# How to speed up when load a larger file use Loadfile() in Tinyxml

Tags: c++, tinyxml

In my project I need append new data to a xml, so I do it like below:
the question is the LoadFile() funcation is so slowly when the xml file is large, and high-cpu, the SaveFile() have same problem. So， How should I speed up in my project.
Thanks you help:)

```
        TiXmlDocument doc(m_filePath.c_str()); 
    (void)doc.LoadFile(); //here is slowly
    if (doc.Error() && (doc.ErrorId()==TiXmlBase::TIXML_ERROR_OPENING_FILE))
    {
        ATS_LOG(ERROR, "Can not open the file:%s", m_filePath.c_str());
        result = false; 
    }
    else
    {
        const TiXmlHandle docH(&doc); 
        TiXmlElement* const element = docH.FirstChildElement("HistoryMsgs").Element();
        TiXmlNode* const pNode=element->ToElement();
        if (pNode!=NULL)
        {
                            //do something that insert new node;
            (void)doc.SaveFile(m_filePath.c_str());//here is slowly too
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TinyXML has quite some performance issues. RapidXML and PugiXML are more preferred. I'm not sure how easy would it be to port your code to a new parser, but I had performance issues once with TinyXML and then  switched to PugiXML. You might check out a discussion on C++ parsers on:
[What is the best open XML parser for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c)