# Jsoup like html parser for C++

Tags: c++, html, css-selectors, jsoup

I have been writing some codes to get some data from some pages in Java and Jsoup was on of the best libraries to work with. But, Unfortunately I have to port the whole code to C/C++. But I a cannot find any decent html parser to use on c++. Is there any Jsoup like library for C++ or How can similar results be achieved?

[Currently I am using Curl to get the source of the pages and roaming the internet to find a html parser]

Comment: There are [really good XML parsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686) out there, but I am not aware of a good C++ HTML specific parser

Comment: Would JNI be a solution for you?

Comment: I might not want to use JNI. I have not much idea about it. And also I want to make the project less dependent[except necessary].

Comment: And also for a clarification, what I need is just parsing the document and get some values from it and a reliable method to return using CSS Selector[preferably] or Xpath. Also, it would be very good if the parser is very fast, since I would be browsing over 100,000 pages to maintain a database.

Comment: I don't know how things compare to Jsoup, but see [Comparison of HTML parsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers) for a detailed list of parsers in various languages.

Comment: Google open sourced Gumbo: https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, i guess there's no parser like Jsoup for C++ ...

Beside the libraries which are already mentioned here, there's a good overview about C++ (some C too) parser here: [**Free C or C++ XML Parser Libraries**](http://lars.ruoff.free.fr/xmlcpp/)

For parsing i used [**TinyXML-2**](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/index.html) for (Html-) DOM parsing; it's a very small (only 2 files) library that runs on most OS (even non-desktop).

[**LibXml**](http://xmlsoft.org/)

- push and pull parser (DOM, SAX)
- Validation
- XPath and XPointer support
- Cross-Plattform / good documentation

[**Apache Xerxces**](https://xerces.apache.org/)

- push and pull parser (DOM, SAX)
- Validation
- No XPath support (but a package for this?)
- Cross-Plattform / good documentation

If you are on C++ CLI, check out [**NSoup**](https://nsoup.codeplex.com/) - a Jsoup port for .NET.

Some more:

- [htmlcxx - html and css APIs for C++](http://htmlcxx.sourceforge.net/)
- [MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (?)
- [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/) (DOM / XPath and Unicode support)
- [LibCSS](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/projects/libcss/) (CSS Parser) / [LibDOM](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/projects/libdom/) (DOM) (however, both in C)
- [hcxselect](http://hcxselect.sourceforge.net/) (CSS selector engine for C++)

Maybe you can combine a DOM Model / Parser and a CSS selector together?

Comment: I did not even think of only a CSS Selector!!! [How fool of me!!! I get the source of the page by cURL and CSS selector will do the rest!!!]. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: LibDOM is not C++ compatible as it uses the keyword namespace as a member variable of a structure.

Answer (score 9):

If you are familiar with Qt Framework the most convenient way is using [QWebElement](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2009/04/07/qwebelement-sees-the-light-do-i-hear-a-booyakasha/) (Reference [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qwebelement.html)).

Otherwise, (as another post suggests) using [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to convert HTML to a valid XML and then using an XML parser such as [libxml++](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/) is a good option. You can find a sample code showing these two steps [here](http://www.mostthingsweb.com/2013/02/parsing-html-with-c/).

Comment: +1 for mentioning QWebElement. Didn't even know it exists.

Comment: I did not knew that either. :D
+1. It's really the simplest solution but also the dependency to Qt is a problem [for me]...

Answer (score 7):

Chromium has an open source [parser](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/b69618018614278cda72077611adc093f460dc57/Source/core/html/parser/HTMLDocumentParser.cpp).  Also, the [Google gumbo-parser](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser) looks cool.

Comment: Much appreciated. Let's hope it floats up to the top voted answers

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a html parser lib for c++, check it out
https://github.com/HamedMasafi/HtmlParser/

This library can parse html or css and convert it to a tree model. You can search in parsed html by methods like: get_by_id, get_by_class_name, get_by_tag_name, and also there is a question method that you can search via css selector (only tag, id, class, nested childs selectors supported for now).

After finding a child you can change it's attributes and in final you can print a html into std::string in compact and pretty mode.

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

Comment: OK, thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xerces2](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/dom.html) as DOM parser.

Or use [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) to clean up the HTML and convert it to XHTML then parse the XML with [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/) or similar XML parser. And since pugixml is a non-validating parser, it might as well work on the raw HTML without the need of runnin HTML Tidy on it first.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind calling out to python from C++, you could use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  At least the name is right!

Seriously - it's a nice, no-nonsense HTML parser.  I haven't tried calling out to it from C++, although it *should* be straightforwards.