# Extracting HTML tags with C++

Tags: c++, html, xml, regex, parsing

I'm currently working on a crawler written with C++ for a search engine, the crawler will get a list of HTML files and need to extract HTML tags and put them into a file.

I heard about using an XML parser but I can't figure out how to convert the HTML file to XHTML, in addition to that, converting to XHTML is expensive in term of performance. And html parsers in C++ are almost non-existent.

The third way is using boost regex to extract these tags from the HTML files, but I need to extract all the tags(p, h1, h2, a ...) so it will be a little bit too long to do.

Any other solutions to how can I get HTML tags in C++?

Comment: This seems to be a dupe of [Jsoup like html parser for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921697/jsoup-like-html-parser-for-c) which, by the way, was the first google result for "c++ html parsing". And the answer is: you want [`QWebElement`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebelement.html).

Comment: i'm coding in linux , can i use QT in it ?

Comment: Qt is free, multiplatform software, so, yes (I use mostly Linux myself)...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to parse it using xml parser, I usually use RapidXML Check it [here](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/)

You will get all tags and attributes of the HTML file.

Comment: can you just explain more, like how can i get the xml file from html
thanks

Comment: Check out this [http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1parsing], it shows how you can get `xml_document<> doc;`, which includes all tags and attributes.

Comment: Check out this question also: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808022/how-to-parse-the-xml-file-in-rapidxml>

Answer (score -1):

You could use [HTML parser](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html) from [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/).