# Is there any function for xml creating and parsing in vc++ 6.0?

Tags: xml, visual-c++

Can anyone please help me to know the functions available in *vc 6.0* or *vc++ 6.0* library for xml parsing and creation.

Actually I am beginer in *vc++* and I have to work with *vc++ 6.0* only. I know there are api's in *vc++ 8.0* but I want api's for *vc++ 6.0* version.

Please help me if you know any function in v*c++ 6.0* library.

Thanks and regards

Safiuddin S.K.

Comment: you can incorporate any of the parsers noted in a previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c

Answer (score 0):

Try MSXML or XmlLite. See [MSXML references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [XmlLite references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms752872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more informations.