# C++ cin.getline to char array

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream, getline

I have declared an array: `names[1000];`
and another array, `data[1000];`, to store the data temporarily

and later used an `ifstream` to read data from an `XML` file.

then later, I used `cin.getline(data, 300)` to put the data into `data[]` array.

but when I assign `data[]` array to `names[]` array, an error occurs:

```
invalid operands of types char[1000] and char[1000] to binary operator>>
```

code:

```
char data[1000];
char names[1000];


ifstream openFile("myfile.xml");

if(!openFile)
{
    cout<<"File not found! please re-enter filename"<<endl;
}

while (openFile.getline (data, 300))
{
    if (data[0] == '<' && data[1] == 'n') // to only check the <name> xml tag
    {
        cout<<data<<endl;
        data >> names;
    }
}
```

Any idea why I cant assign data array to names array?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using C-style strings and not `std::string` ?

Comment: I have to use array for checking ( [0] =='<' && [1] =='n' ) to check the start of the data if they consist certain characters...

Comment: You can, of course, do that with proper C++ strings (`std::string`) as well as pretty much anything else that you might want to do with old style C strings. The difference though is that it's a lot easier and a lot safer/more robust with `std::string`.

Comment: @taurette You can easily do that with C++ strings.

Comment: @taurette you can do that with `std::string` (i.e. using `[]` for indexing, just check length first).

Comment: thanks! using std::string fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

">>" operator is usually defined for streams, but data is just an array.
if you want to copy the content, use strncpy from string.h:

```
strncpy(names, data, 1000);
```

if you want to treat your string/array as stream, try stringstream.

BTW, you may want to use C++ string instead of character arrays -- it's more convenient (but not so efficient).

Comment: @taurette if you are into XML, then please consider XML library in the long term, because reading line-by-line is not reliable (one can have line breaks in funny places). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c

Answer (score 0):

Because you can't assign arrays. At all.

You may want to take a look at [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which can be assigned among other cool things.

If you want to stick to `char` arrays, you can do the following :

```
std::copy(std::begin(data), std::end(data), std::begin(names));
```

Or (to avoid copying trash after the 300th element) :

```
std::copy(std::begin(data), std::begin(data) + 301, std::begin(names));
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator `>>` is not used for assignment ! You could assign using `strncpy` like this

```
strncpy(names, data, 1000);
```

and add the include

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: Array names are not lvalues, thus can't be assigned.

Comment: I meant to assign pointers so they point to same container. But I see now that this will be a problem because the content will be erased when reading a new line. So `strncpy` is the solution. Editing my answer

Comment: [**Array names are not pointers either**.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607128/in-c-are-arrays-pointers-or-used-as-pointers)

Comment: From link; "If the expression `a` (which is an `int [10]`) appears in a context other than as the operand of the sizeof or & operators, then its type is implicitly converted to `int *`, and its value is the address of the first element."

Comment: Indeed. But a conversion yields an rvalue, a temporary if you prefer, which by definition can't be assigned for native types.

Comment: I hope I helped you understand arrays better, they are confusing to many :)