# Is there a way to parse Android manifest in C/C++?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-manifest

I'm trying to write a small application that should check parse the AndroidManifest.xml from the APK in C/C++. I know that there are ways to do it in JAVA/C#, or in python, but I need C.

Is there a way of doing it? and if not, is there a good documentation regarding the Binary format of the AndroidManifest.xml in the apk package?

Thanks in advance,
K.

Comment: Any thoughts to just using a vanilla xml parser? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c

Comment: The XML is compiled to a binary format when the APK is built. @AgentK, I know of no documentation, but the work done by apktool and androguard might be useful. https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/source/browse/brut.apktool/apktool-lib/src/main/java/brut/androlib/res/AndrolibResources.java contains the start of the logic to turn the binary back into text. If you can't find anything else, this could help you write your own C version and then use a standard parser to read the XML.

Comment: Thanks @ErikNedwidek I will have a look at it.