# How to canonicalize XML in C++

Tags: c++, xml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, in-app-purchase

I have an in-app purchase support in my Windows Phone app, and want to add a server-side receipt verification. However, I want to canonicalize the receiptXml before sending it to server, so I am looking for a ready-to-use approach for XML canonicalization on Windows Phone.

Comment: So you're looking for a library (which is off-topic for SO)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best open XML parser for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c)

Answer (score 2):

Good libraries for C++ XML parsing are [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/), [TinyXML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml), [pugixml](http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/) or maybe (depending on work env) [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/)