# Read XML from a string in C++ / Unix

Tags: c++, xml, linux, string, unix

I'm looking for a simple way to read XML that is contained in a string variable in C++ for Unix systems. I have found a lot of solutions for xml files but not a lot about XML that is contained in a string variable.

Do I have to use functions such as find(), etc. or is there a library that I missed that could do the job for me ?

---

**EDIT:**

If I have the following XML in a string, how can I read it ? (with pugixml for example)

```
string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>";
     xml += "<people><person><name>Toto</name><age>20</age></person>";
     xml += "<person><name>John</name><age>42</age></person></people>";
```

Comment: Do you want to read the xml in C++ or on the unix command line?

Comment: @Leon In C++ but I don't want a solution for Windows. ;)

Comment: I can't give a definitive answer as I have never had to parse xml in c++, but from experience using lxml in python I think you should have a look at libxml2

Comment: have a look at [What XML parser should I use in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9387610) and [Best open XML parser for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/170686)

Comment: If you don't need it to be super-duper function complete but you want it to be fast and easy to use, I recommend [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/).

Comment: I added an example of a string that contains XML in my question. Can someone give me a code sample to parse it ?

Comment: @Aleph0, the resulting xml is invalid (unless you remove the duplicated line). Either way, [the pugixml documentation](http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/manual/loading.html) will give you an example (search for "Loading document from memory" within the page).

Comment: ***Every*** mature XML library will support loading of strings... just pick one and read the docs/tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to use Tinyxml2 library.
Especially XMLDocument::Parse - is your best catch (http://grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_document.html#a1819bd34f540a7304c105a6232d25a1f)

And after loading your string in XMLDocument - you can navigate it via tinyxml2 tools further.

Exact example in documentation -> http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2docs/_example-3.html

Comment: Thanks, it is  exactly what I was looking for. I just had to replace XMLDocument by TiXmlDocument and XMLElement by TiXmlElement in the example.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using [pugixml](https://pugixml.org/):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "pugixml.hpp"

int main()
{
    using namespace pugi;

    std::string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>";
    xml += "<people><person><name>Toto</name><age>20</age></person>";
    xml += "<person><name>John</name><age>42</age></person></people>";

    xml_document doc;
    xml_parse_result res = doc.load(xml.c_str());

    if(!res)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << res.description() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    for(auto&& person: doc.child("people").children("person"))
    {
        std::cout << "name: " << person.child("name").text().as_string() << '\n';
        std::cout << " age: " << person.child("age").text().as_string() << '\n';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
name: Toto
 age: 20

name: John
 age: 42
```

Comment: I managed to make it work with tinyxml and it looks more or less the same. Too bad I can't validate 2 answers but thank you for this answer. ;)