# c++ How to retrieve a text value from an XML node

Tags: c++, xml

Having an XML node object (the parent one), how can I retrieve the text value of one of the children nodes in C++?

Comment: _"Having an XML node object"_ Are you using an XML library? Which one?

Comment: Indeed, it's a private Library. But I can use boost

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: _"Indeed, it's a private Library"_ So you have looked at that library API (or at least public headers) and didn't find any ways to enumerate XML node's children? May be it is time to switch to another well known XML library? There are plenty of them

Comment: @Daveddd: If you are using Boost then give a try of [Property Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/property_tree.html).

Comment: ***it's a private Library*** How can we possibly help when we don't have the library you use??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use the method on your parent that gives you the child node you want.
Then use the method on that object that lets you access its text.

If you happen to use [RapidXML](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/), which I like to [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/170912/5903309), there's an easy parsing example found [here](https://gist.github.com/JSchaenzle/2726944).

The essential part is:

---

```
 root_node = doc.first_node("MyBeerJournal.xml");
```

reads an XML file called MyBeerJournal.xml

---

```
for (xml_node<> * brewery_node = root_node->first_node("Brewery"); brewery_node; brewery_node = brewery_node->next_sibling())
{
   ...
}
```

lets you iterate over the nodes, starting with the one called `Brewery`.

---

```
auto beerName = brewery_node->first_attribute("name")->value();
```

finally lets you access the text value of the desired attribute, in this case `name`

Comment: You could just write "Use API of your library" )))

Comment: You last edit makes this "link only" answer, which is not welcomed here at SO, you should provide essential code snippet

Comment: @mvidelgauz you're right, wait a sec

Comment: No, I suggest you to wait until we know what library is actually used, otherwise you will "shoot at the dark"

Comment: @mvidelgauz the OPs comment `Indeed, it's a private Library. But I can use boost` makes me believe he's unsure on which library to use

Comment: IMHO, you are wasting your time guessing. But that's your call of course

Comment: @mvidelgauz eh, you're probably right. Guess the possibility of juicy rep blinded me

Comment: Welcome to SO and associated symptoms